# Store Images in application data folder on installing

Tags: android

I have many static images in my application at start, 
I'm adding images in classes as `Base64` and encode it when application start then storing in Internal Storage by `FileOutputStream`.

I need to put those images in application's data as a files on installing application (without encoding).

Is there any way ?

Comment: Why do you want to store images without encoding?

Comment: Trying to enhance my application speed and performance @NabinBhandari

Comment: If so, store them as JPEG files and use Glide library to load them.

Comment: @NabinBhandari That's what I need,  how to store as JPEG files in data application on installing app ?

Comment: Oh, FYI, JPEG is also an encoding. So, where are those images located originally and where are they going to be used?

Comment: I have my images for example on my PC, need to add them on data folder of my application on moblie, I know some application thats have data and images on installing app, I'm asking if there is a way to put those images in application data directory without coding (android studio project directory) or something like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply store your image files in the **assets** folder and access them from the app using following method:

```
public static Bitmap getImageFromAsset(Context context, String fileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    in.close();
    return bitmap;
}
```

You can also store them in the **drawable** folder (or drawable-nodpi if you want to preserve size) and use it to display in `ImageView`.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```